# Python - List comphrehension with test to avoid division by zero

Tags: python, list, numpy

`a` and `b` are 1 dimensional numpy arrays (or python lists):

I am doing this:

```
>>> c = [x/y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Occasionally `b` has a zero in it - so a division by zero error occurs.

How can I conditionally check for a 0 value in `b` and set the corresponding element of `c` to 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`if-else` condition](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) inside list comprehension:

```
>>> c = [x/y if y else 0 for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: Or even more reduced, just `...if y else...`.

Comment: As for me, I like it better with `if y != 0` (It seems more explicit in this case).

Comment: @mgilson. But it wouldn't matter in this case right? I know `y` can be false for many other values.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter for this case.  It's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [ternary expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) inside the list comprehension:

```
[x/y if y!= 0 else 0 for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `numpy` does what you want by default:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([0,1,3])
>>> a / b
array([0, 2, 1])
```

As @Jaime pointed out, if at least one `array` is of type float, then division by 0 results in `inf`, so you need to do this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float')
>>> b = np.array([0,1,3], dtype='float')
>>> c = a / b
>>> c
array([ inf,   2.,   1.])
>>> c[c == np.inf] = 0
>>> c
array([ 0.,  2.,  1.])
```

Comment: Actually, if either of your arrays is of type float, it will place an `inf` at every position where a division by zero happens.

Answer (score 1):

The old syntax:

```
[y and x/y or 0 for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

The new syntax:

```
[x/y if y else 0 for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

It should be noted that numpy handles this perfectly by itself:

```
numpy.arange(-3, 7, dtype='float') / numpy.arange(-5, 5, dtype='float')

array([ 0.6       ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333, -0.        , -1.        ,
               inf,  3.        ,  2.        ,  1.66666667,  1.5       ])
```

Comment: In this case, I think you could get away with just `y and x/y for x,y in zip(a,b)` ... But that's quite tricky to parse :)

Comment: You're right, didn't even think about that :) But for the sake of readability I'll leave it