# How to return 0 with divide by zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, error-handling, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to perform an element wise divide in python, but if a zero is encountered, I need the quotient to just be zero.

For example:

```
array1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
array2 = np.array([0, 1, 1])

array1 / array2 # should be np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

I could always just use a for-loop through my data, but to really utilize numpy's optimizations, I need the divide function to return 0 upon divide by zero errors instead of ignoring the error.

Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem [numpy.seterr()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr) can return values upon errors. Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I could get the best out of numpy while setting my own divide by zero error handling?

Comment: In my python version (Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.) that is exactly the output that you get. With a warning.

Comment: The most succinct correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977222/2116338

Comment: In case you are doing `x / np.abs(x)`: `np.sign()` maps R -> {-1, 0, 1}.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

In numpy v1.7+, you can take advantage of the "where" option for [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).  You can do things in one line and you don't have to deal with the errstate context manager.

```
>>> a = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
>>> b = np.array([ 0, 0, 0, 2, 2], dtype=float)

# If you don't pass `out` the indices where (b == 0) will be uninitialized!
>>> c = np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=b!=0)
>>> print(c)
[ 0.   0.   0.   1.   1.5]
```

In this case, it does the divide calculation anywhere 'where' b does not equal zero.  When b does equal zero, then it remains unchanged from whatever value you originally gave it in the 'out' argument.

Comment: If `a` and/or `b` might be integer arrays, then it's the same concept, you just need to explicitly set the correct output type: `c = np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=float), where=b!=0)`

Comment: `out=np.zeros_like(a)` is critical, as stated in the commented line.

Comment: If I use ```np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=b!=0)```, I get the error ```Assigning to function call which doesn't return```. The weird thing is, I use it twice and the error only pops up once.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in which is fastest, this method is faster than @denis's/@Franck Dernoncourt's answer, running one million cycles I'm getting 8 seconds for this versus 11 seconds for theirs.

Comment: In my case it wasn't only float values precisely equal to zero that need to be 'zeroed', but those values 'close' to zero. So the following is useful `np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=~np.isclose(b,np.zeros_like(b)))` and you can set the `atol` and `rtol` of `isclose` as suits your use case.

Answer (score 57):

Building on @Franck Dernoncourt's answer, fixing -1 / 0  and my bug on scalars:

```
def div0( a, b, fill=np.nan ):
    """ a / b, divide by 0 -> `fill`
        div0( [-1, 0, 1], 0, fill=np.nan) -> [nan nan nan]
        div0( 1, 0, fill=np.inf ) -> inf
    """
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        c = np.true_divide( a, b )
    if np.isscalar( c ):
        return c if np.isfinite( c ) \
            else fill
    else:
        c[ ~ np.isfinite( c )] = fill
        return c
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even catch that bug with @Frank Dernoncourt's code.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do array math and I want 0/0 to result in 0 but I also want to ignore np.NaN in my calculations as well. Will this work for that? Also, I am trying to understand. What does c[ ~ np.isfinite( c )] = 0 do? I've never used ~ in python. What is it for? Thank you

Comment: @user20408, `~` inverts `True` and `False` in numpy arrays: 
`print ~ np.array([ True, False, False ])`.
`c[ ~ np.isfinite( c )] = 0` means:
find the positions where `c` is finite, invert those to NOT finite with `~`,
and set the not-finite values to 0.
See also
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[numpy]+"boolean+indexing"

Answer (score 54):

Building on the other answers, and improving on:

- `0/0` handling by adding `invalid='ignore'` to [`numpy.errstate()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html)
- introducing [`numpy.nan_to_num()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) to convert `np.nan` to `0`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,0,1,1,2], dtype='float')
b = np.array([0,1,0,1,3], dtype='float')

with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    c = np.true_divide(a,b)
    c[c == np.inf] = 0
    c = np.nan_to_num(c)

print('c: {0}'.format(c))
```

Output:

```
c: [ 0.          0.          0.          1.          0.66666667]
```

Comment: Good job for checking `0/0` as well as `1/0` errors.

Comment: I tried your method with the example arrays given in [DStauffman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977222/6126315) and it seems to result in very high numbers instead of np.inf, which remains at the final result

Comment: I would discourage this approach. If either `a` or `b` contains `NaN`, your solution suddenly gives `0` as a result. This can easily hide errors in your code and is absolutely unexpected.

Comment: According to recent [numpy manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html?highlight=numpy%20nan_to_num#numpy.nan_to_num) 
nan_to_num() takes values to substitute for positive inf and negative inf as well.  
`numpy.nan_to_num(x, copy=True, nan=0.0, posinf=None, neginf=None)` is the signature.

Answer (score 20):

#### DEPRECATED (PYTHON 2 SOLUTION):

**One-liner** (throws warning)

```
np.nan_to_num(array1 / array2)
```

Comment: Divide by zero (confusingly, since it's incorrect!) gives `inf` in numpy, not undefined or `nan`. So this will set divide by zero to *[a very large number](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)*, not `0` as one might expect and the OP asks. You can get around this by setting `posinf=0`.

Comment: Ah, yeah this answer is so old that the code is in Python 2 (where it works).

Answer (score 17):

Try doing it in two steps. Division first, then replace.

```
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    result = numerator / denominator
    result[denominator == 0] = 0
```

The `numpy.errstate` line is optional, and just prevents numpy from telling you about the "error" of dividing by zero, since you're already intending to do so, and handling that case.

Comment: You should probably perform the division in the context `np.errstate(divide='ignore'):`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Fair point. I've edited the answer to include the context. `divide='warn'` could also be useful if s/he wanted to still be notified.

Answer (score 3):

You can also replace based on `inf`, only if the array dtypes are floats, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17345387/1461850):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float')
>>> b = np.array([0,1,3], dtype='float')
>>> c = a / b
>>> c
array([ inf,   2.,   1.])
>>> c[c == np.inf] = 0
>>> c
array([ 0.,  2.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer I found searching a related question was to manipulate the output based upon whether the denominator was zero or not.

Suppose `arrayA` and `arrayB` have been initialized, but `arrayB` has some zeros. We could do the following if we want to compute `arrayC = arrayA / arrayB` safely.

In this case, whenever I have a divide by zero in one of the cells, I set the cell to be equal to `myOwnValue`, which in this case would be zero

```
myOwnValue = 0
arrayC = np.zeros(arrayA.shape())
indNonZeros = np.where(arrayB != 0)
indZeros = np.where(arrayB = 0)

# division in two steps: first with nonzero cells, and then zero cells
arrayC[indNonZeros] = arrayA[indNonZeros] / arrayB[indNonZeros]
arrayC[indZeros] = myOwnValue # Look at footnote
```

Footnote: In retrospect, this line is unnecessary anyways, since `arrayC[i]` is instantiated to zero. But if were the case that `myOwnValue != 0`, this operation would do something.

Comment: indZeros = np.where(arrayB = 0) this line should be indZeros = np.where(arrayB == 0)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with try/except to manage any kind of those numpy RuntimeWarnings:

```
with np.errstate(all='raise'):
    try:
        array3 = array1/array2
    except:
        array3 = array1 # Give whatever default value you like
```

Answer (score -1):

An other solution worth mentioning :

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float')
>>> b = np.array([0,1,3], dtype='float')
>>> b_inv = np.array([1/i if i!=0 else 0 for i in b])
>>> a*b_inv
array([0., 2., 1.])
```