# numpy: Invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays and I am trying to divide one with the other and at the same time, I want to make sure that the entries where the divisor is 0, should just be replaced with 0.

So, I do something like:

```
log_norm_images = np.where(b_0 > 0, np.divide(diff_images, b_0), 0)
```

This gives me a run time warning of:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

Now, I wanted to see what was going on and I did the following:

```
xx = np.isfinite(diff_images)
print (xx[xx == False])

xx = np.isfinite(b_0)
print (xx[xx == False])
```

However, both of these return empty arrays meaning that all the values in the arrays are finite. So, I am not sure where the invalid value is coming from. I am assuming checking b_0 > 0 in the np.where function takes care of the divide by 0.

The shape of the two arrays are (96, 96, 55, 64) and (96, 96, 55, 1)

Comment: Why would `xx` be `False` and a dict?

Comment: I think isfinite returns a boolean array. So, I am looking for places where the values are NOT finite.

Comment: Try `[x for x in xx if x == False]`. You're just trying to fetch the key `False`

Comment: You mean like this:  print (xx[x for x in xx if x == False]). This raises a syntax error.

Comment: Related I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26248654/846892

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have this covered with the np.where function where the division should only happen when the divisor is greater than 0

Comment: For what it's worth, you can "invert" a boolean array using the `~` operator.  E.g. `print your_data[~np.isfinite(your_data)]`.

Comment: Follow-up question: what does it say about `false_divide`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may have a `NAN`, `INF`, or `NINF` floating around somewhere.  Try this:

```
np.isfinite(diff_images).all()
np.isfinite(b_0).all()
```

If one or both of those returns `False`, that's likely the cause of the runtime error.

Comment: Thanks. They both return true though :/

Comment: It seems like you can safely ignore the warning.  I tried doing this with two random arrays (and an arbitrary element in one of the arrays set to 0) - I get the runtime warning the first time I run `np.where`, but if I repeat the exact same expression a second time I don't get the warning.

Comment: I decided to ignore this after verifying that the output indeed looks like it should. So, using "with np.errstate(invalid='ignore', divide='ignore'):"

Comment: @Luca I think you should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

The reason you get the runtime warning when running this:

```py
log_norm_images = np.where(b_0 > 0, np.divide(diff_images, b_0), 0)
```

is that the inner expression

```py
np.divide(diff_images, b_0)
```

gets evaluated first, and is run on all elements of `diff_images` and `b_0` (even though you end up ignoring the elements that involve division-by-zero).  In other words, the warning happens *before* the code that ignores those elements.  That is why it's a warning and not an error: there are legitimate cases like this one where the division-by-zero is not a problem because it's being handled in a later operation.

Answer (score 3):

Another useful Numpy command is nan_to_num(diff_images)
By default it replaces in a Numpy array; NaN to zero, -INF to -(large number) and +INF to +(large number)

You can change the defaults, see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Answer (score 0):

As @drammock pointed out, the cause of the warning is that some of the values in `b_0` is 0 and the runtime warning is generated before the `np.where` is evaluated.  While @Luca's suggestion of running `np.errstate(invalid='ignore', divide='ignore'):"` before the `np.where` will prevent the warning in this case, there may be other legitimate cases where this warning could be generated.  For instance, corresponding elements of b_0 and diff_images are set to `np.inf`, which would return `np.nan`.

So to prevent warnings for known cases (i.e. b_0 = 0) and allow for warnings of unknown cases, evaluate the `np.where` first then evaluate the arithmetic:

```
#First, create log_norm_images
log_norm_images = np.zeros(b_0.shape)
#Now get the valid indexes
valid = where(b_0 > 0)
#Lastly, evaluate the division problem at the valid indexes
log_norm_images[valid] = np.divide(diff_images[valid], b_0[valid])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
num = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
den = np.array([1,1,0,1,1])
res = np.array([None]*5)
ix  = (den!=0)
res[ix] = np.divide( num[ix], den[ix] )
print(res)
```

[1.0 2.0 None 4.0 5.0]