# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide for text classification

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating the probability distribution given by an array and encountering this error

```
C:\Users\malsa876\PycharmProjects\ReqPrioritization\Semi_EM_NB.py:241: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  proba_array = np.true_divide(proba_array_unormalized, np.sum(proba_array_unormalized, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis])

total likelihood: -1053924.5147916302
total likelihood: -1054903.0540410974
total likelihood: -1058234.6120591105
total likelihood: -1059247.4669063047
total likelihood: -1063169.2473161623
total likelihood: -1068871.708044591
total likelihood: -1076802.3646161058
total likelihood: -1084315.921876911
total likelihood: -1086195.0970660546
total likelihood: -1087372.3810061032
total likelihood: -1087940.417901436
total likelihood: -1087940.417901436
stopping time
```

[image]

Comment: Did you already take a look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27843037/6273251) or try what was suggested in it? If so did that help?