# How to avoid "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide dx = np.abs(FY)/np.sqrt(FX**2+FY**2)"

Tags: python, numpy

```
I_pad=np.pad(img0,1,'edge') #array padding

FY=np.gradient(I_pad,axis=0)
FX=np.gradient(I_pad,axis=1)


dx = np.abs(FY)/np.sqrt(FX**2+FY**2)
dy = np.abs(FX)/np.sqrt(FX**2+FY**2)
```

I am trying to avoid the RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide in NumPy.
and unable to find a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy: Invalid value encountered in true\_divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842884/numpy-invalid-value-encountered-in-true-divide)

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: Line 7 and 8(dx and dy) both are giving the same runtime warning