# Error raised in code that shouldn't run according to lazy evaluation

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, runtime-error, divide-by-zero

I have the following code as part of a function:

```
px = x2 - x1
py = y2 - y1
pz = z2 - z1

div = px*px + py*py    

u = ((x0 - x1) * px + (y0 - y1) * py) / div
```

the `u=` line returns `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide` when run. This is because occasionally the `div=` line returns zero.

However, if I rewrite the `u=` line as:

```
u = np.where(div != 0, ((x0 - x1) * px + (y0 - y1) * py) / div, 0)
```

it still returns the same runtime warning.

This code outputs the desired numbers however I thought that the `np.where` function was lazy. If this is not the case then there are potential speed ups in other bits of code I have written (hence I'm asking this question).
What am I missing? Does the `np.where` function calculate both the 'True' and 'False inputs and then select one depending on the boolean?

Note, this is the solution I've ended up with:

```
np.seterr(invalid='ignore')
u = np.where(div != 0, ((x0 - x1) * px + (y0 - y1) * py) / div, 0)
np.seterr(invalid='warn')
```

although this works fine too:

```
u = np.zeros_like(div)
divb = div != 0
u[divb] = ((x0[divb] - x1[divb]) * px[divb] + 
        (y0[divb] - y1[divb]) * py[divb]) / div[divb]
```

(which is kind of what I thought `np.where` did...)

Both these solutions are around the same speed but both are slower than just the `np.where` function on its own.

Any explanations/suggestions welcome!
Thanks.

Comment: is `div` a floating point number?

Comment: `np.where` does not (and can not) implement lazy evaluation.  All its arguments are evaluated (as are all the arguments to any python function) before the function is called.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thanks, will have to change some of the stuff I've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a divide by 0 issue that programmers have been working around since the earliest vectorized languages (e.g. APL, MATLAB).

One solution which I've used in the past is to (conditionally) add 1 to the divisor:

```
u = ((x0 - x1) * px + (y0 - y1) * py) / (div + (div==0))
```

It doesn't work in all cases, but it might in this, since it appears the `div` will be 0 only if both `px` and `py` are 0.  In that case the numerator is also 0.  `0/1 = 0`.

Or clipping `div` with a small value (this may be the fastest solution):

```
..../np.maximum(div,1e-16)
```

A quick search on SO for `numpy divide by zero` turned up other questions.  For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26248892/901925
suggests using `errstate` context to turn off the warning:

```
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    u = .../div
```

`divide` works for cases like `1/0`, while `invalid` is needed for `0/0` cases.  But `ignore` ends up putting either `inf` or `nan` in the return array.  So you still need to test for `(div==0)` to get a `0` value.

Though I rather like the appearance of this form:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    u = np.where(div==0, 0, .../div)
```

Warren's comment explains why `where` doesn't work.  The arguments are evaluate before being passed to the function.  Lazy-evaluation requires the cooperation of the Python interpreter.  It is normally part of the syntax (e.g. `if`,`|`,`&`).

Comment: Thanks hpaulj... Appreciate the detail, I've opted for the `with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):` solution, its cleaner than what I had before.