# Apply logarithm only on positive entries of array

Tags: python, scipy

SciPy thoughtfully provides the scipy.log function, which will take an array and then log all elements in that array. Is there a way to log only the positive (i.e. positive non-zero) elements of an array?

Comment: Use [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to select the positive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `where()`?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 1., -1., 0.5, -0.5, 0., 2. ])
la = np.where(a>0, np.log(a), a) 
print(la)
# Gives [ 0.         -1.         -0.69314718 -0.5         0.          0.69314718]
```

Comment: Or - ```a[a>0] = np.log(a[a>0])```

Comment: As discovered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/28836231/901925 the `log` is evaluated at all values, not just the positive ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution that keeps the original array and leaves non-positive values unchanged:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: a = np.array([ 1., -1., 0.5, -0.5, 0., 2. ])
In [3]: loga = np.log(a)
In [4]: loga
Out[4]: array([ 0., nan, -0.69314718, nan, -inf, 0.69314718 ])

In [5]: # Remove nasty nanses and infses
In [6]: loga[np.where(~np.isfinite(loga))] = a[np.where(~np.isfinite(loga))]
In [7]: loga
Out[7]: array([ 0., -1., -0.69314718, -0.5,  0., 0.69314718])
```

Here, `np.where(~np.isfinite(loga))` returns the indexes of non-finite entries in the `loga` array, and we replace these values with the corresponding originals from `a`.

Comment: Check your answer.  Your final output of `loga` is equal to the original `a`.  Copy-paste mistake?  Also, you should actually have `loga[np.where(~np.isfinite(loga))] = a[np.where(~np.isfinite(loga))]`, otherwise you'll assign the wrong values to the elements where `loga` is not finite.

Comment: You're right @Warren Weckesser: thanks as ever. I was a bit quick to transcribe from my terminal.

Comment: I think @Dietrich has provided the best answer to this question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With boolean indexing:

```
In [695]: a = np.array([ 1. , -1. ,  0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  2. ])    
In [696]: I=a>0
In [697]: a[I]=np.log(a[I])
In [698]: a
Out[698]: 
array([ 0.        , -1.        , -0.69314718, -0.5       ,  0.        ,
        0.69314718])
```

or if you just want to keep the `logged` terms

```
In [707]: np.log(a[I])
Out[707]: array([ 0.        , -0.69314718,  0.69314718])
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but I'll just put this here:

```
for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        if array[i,j] > 0:
            array[i,j]=log(array[i,j])
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way of doing it which didn't need to explicitly loop over all the elements of the array - the array can get quite large.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize a custom function.

```
import numpy as np

def pos_log(x):
    if x > 0:
        return np.log(x)
    return x

v_pos_log = np.vectorize(pos_log, otypes=[np.float])

result = v_pos_log(np.array([-1, 1]))
#>>> np.array([-1, 0])
```

But as the documentation for `numpy.vectorize` says "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."