# Python: How to enable division by zero and return zero value?

Tags: python, division, divide-by-zero

I have this following code that do help me reshape each lines in a file and perform simple division calculation. When divided by zero, this error occurred. Any helps are greatly appreciated.

```
print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide

print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import csv

binary = np.genfromtxt('binary.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 101, 4))
single = np.genfromtxt('single.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 4))
divisi = np.genfromtxt('divisi.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 1, 4))

print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
```

The inclusion of this 4 lines or code still cannot solve it.

```
try:
    print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
except Exception:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy: Return 0 with divide by zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read this page. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

As far as I know, when division by zero errors occur, It is recommended to use the code as below

```
try:
    print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your `print` in a `try:except` like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import csv

binary = np.genfromtxt('binary.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 101, 4))
single = np.genfromtxt('single.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 4))
divisi = np.genfromtxt('divisi.csv', delimiter = ',').reshape((-1, 1, 4))

try:
    print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
except Exception:
    print(0)  #or print whatever you want when you divide by zero
```

Comment: This page might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if (divisi == 0):
    print (0)
else:
    print(np.sum(single / divisi * binary, axis = -1))
```