# Replace division by zero numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I'm doing a matrix by matrix pointwise division however there are some zeros in the divisor matrix. This results in a warning and in some NaNs. I want these to map to 0, which I can do like this:

```
edge_map = (xy/(x_norm*y_norm))
edge_map[np.isnan(edge_map)] = 0
```

However there are two issues with this, first of all it still gives a warning (I don't like warnings) and second of all this requires a second pass over the matrix (not sure if this is unavoidable) and efficiency is very important for this part of the code. Ideas?

Comment: Yes so this would mean I do need the second pass, any clue about the warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26248892/382936 suggests using the `numpy.errstate(divide='ignore')` context to suppress the warning. Also see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate

Comment: This is a good question. A `where` function also triggers the warning as the result is calculated. Masks are probably your best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the fastest solution, but the `where` function does trigger the error as it precalculates the solutions:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4

xy = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)
x_norm = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)
y_norm = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)

xy_norm = x_norm*y_norm

edge_map = np.where(xy_norm == 0, xy_norm, xy/xy_norm)

print(xy)
print(xy_norm)
print(edge_map)
```

Comment: This combined with "with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):" solves the problem and is faster than my own solution, thanks

Comment: I have added type conversions, otherwise the divisions all give zero.

Answer (score 1):

While [Chiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37533202/6950750)'s solution works for this example, it might get expensive as `np.where` is not lazy. You have to calculate both possible outputs `xy_norm` and `xy/xy_norm` for all arguments. If this is not desired, you can just calculate the output, which typically requires a few more lines:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4

xy = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)
x_norm = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)
y_norm = np.random.randint(4, size=(n,n)).astype(float)

xy_norm = x_norm*y_norm

edge_map = np.zeros_like(xy_norm)
non_zero = xy_norm != 0
edge_map[non_zero] = xy[non_zero]/xy_norm[non_zero]

print(xy)
print(xy_norm)
print(edge_map)
```

Here we avoid the division for all elements where `xy_norm` is zero. As there typically are few zeros and division is not terribly expensive, it's probably not worth from a performance point of view.
Alternatively you can change

```
edge_map[non_zero] = xy[non_zero]/xy_norm[non_zero]
```

to

```
edge_map = np.divide(xy, xy_norm, out=edge_map, where=non_zero)
```

in case you find that more readable ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/how-to-return-0-with-divide-by-zero/26248892)).