# Python: Normalized index gives answer greater than one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am in the process of computing an NDVI index for an image. The NDVI should give values between 0 and 1, however I get much larger values. My data is in a [5000,5000,3] array, and the important bands for the NDVI calculation are the second and the fourth. All entries in my arrays are positive. My code is:

```
nu=imarray[:,:,3]-imarray[:,:,1]
de=imarray[:,:,3]+imarray[:,:,1]
NDVI=div0(nu,de)
```

Where imarray is my array, *nu* is the numerator and *de* is the denominator. I use [denis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86643/denis) excellent div0 function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero), which divides the numerator by the denominator but sets the potential 0/0 to equal 0. Inserting the following print statements for debugging however:

```
print np.amax(NDVI)
print np.amin(NDVI)
```

Gives

```
38.1372781065
0.0
```

I.e. instead of being between -1 and 1, the index is between 0 and 38.1. Mathematically this appears to make little sense, so does anyone know what I am programming incorrectly here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the problem has to be on the values contained within your arrays. I see no other explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Any suggestions what could be wrong? Running np.amin and np.amax on the arrays gives that the fourth band has a min of 0 and a max of 25697, whereas the second band has a min of 0 and a max of 16126. Running `np.isnan(imarray).any()` gives false...

Comment: Don't just look at the min/max values, look at the whole NDVI array. If like 98% of it is within [0,1] just ignore the rest as noise. Min and Max of an array with 25 million elements say nothing about the array. What is the mean/deviation?

Comment: For non-negative x and y, (x-y)/(x+y) is always between -1 and 1. Maybe you have negative values in your array?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I could also get -1, which I completely forgot whilst asking the question, but as written earlier there does not seem to be any negative values...

Comment: Is your data dtype=uint8 by any chance?

Comment: G.Lang Then you are perfectly fine. Having pixels (or array elements) with weird intensities/values happens. I would suggest putting a ``NDVI = min(div0(nu, de), 1)``. Don't sweat it that much.

Comment: @Theguy YES! It was dtype=uint8! Changing it to float immediately gave me values between -1 and 1! Thank you so much, you just saved me hours of confusion. I am new to stackoverflow - any way I can mark your comment as correct? :)

Comment: I've duplicated your problem with `imread`-ing an image. The data is uint8. Then the result of addition and subtraction are wrong. I guess the div0 does manage mask the fact that these are unit8.

Comment: @G.Lang - happy to help. You can upvote the comment that helped you.

Comment: how can it be uint8 and store values as big as 25697?

Comment: @Theguy alas I do not have enough reputation yet, however I will get back to it once I do. Thank you once again for your help!