# How do I accept "divide by zero" as zero? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

So I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[[[2, 2, 3], [0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0]],
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 3]],
[[0, 4, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]]],
[[[2, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0], [2, 0, 3]],
[[0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 3]],
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0]]],
[[[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0]],
[[2, 2, 2], [0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0]],
[[0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0]]]])

array2 = np.array([[[[2, 2, 3], [0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0]],
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0], [0, 2, 3]],
[[0, 4, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]]],
[[[2, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0], [2, 0, 3]],
[[0, 2, 2], [2, 10, 0], [2, 2, 3]],
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0]]],
[[[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0]],
[[2, 2, 2], [0, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0]],
[[0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 0]]]])

def calc(x, y):
    result = y/x
    return result

final_result = []
for x, y in zip(array1, array2):
    final_result.append(calc(np.array(x), np.array(y)))
```

So all in all I have two lists that include some 3D arrays, and then I have defined a function. The last part is where I use each 3D array in the function, and I ultimately end up with a list (`final_result`) of some other 3D arrays where the function has been used on each entry from `array1` and `array2`.

However, as you can see, `array1` which ultimately gives the `x` values in the function does have 0 values in some of the entries. And yes, mathematically, this is no good. But in this case, I really just need the entries that does have a zero `x`-entry to be zero. So it doesn't need to run the function whenever that happens, but just skip it, and leave that entry as zero.

Can this be done?

Comment: What about using:  try and except case to avoid such errors ?

Comment: "I have two lists that include some 3D arrays" - that's not what the code you've posted has. The code uses 2 4-dimensional arrays. Lists of arrays are usually a bad idea; you should only use them if you have a very strong, specific reason to do so.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the right terms then :) What I actually have (not here) is an image converted into a 3D matrix. So what you might see as 4D is actually just slices of the images (CT scan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35696047/1524592). Numpy has a specific way to catch such errors:

```
def calc( a, b ):
    """ ignore / 0, div0( [-1, 0, 1], 0 ) -> [0, 0, 0] """
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        c = np.true_divide( a, b )
        c[ ~ np.isfinite( c )] = 0  # -inf inf NaN
    return c
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I was also going to point out that you can set globally how numpy handles these errors, this documentation page is quite helpful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

Comment: @exp1orer, can you give an example why it is bad to rely on the default numpy settings?

Comment: @Marat I'm not making any claim about whether the default settings are good or bad, it depends on the use. In general, I think that nico's suggestion of using a context manager to be explicit about where you expect these errors to occur, is probably best.

Comment: @exp1orer thank you. I think this comment adds some value to the answer