# efficient way of column sum and reciprocal in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I am working with large matrices(up to million X million).I want to column sum each column in a matrix and put the reciprocal of each column sum in the respective column elements where non zero elements are there.I have done two attempts on this but I still want a faster method of computation and since some columns are zero cant do direct np.reciprocal.
Here are my attempts:

```
A=np.array([[0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
d=sc.shape(A)[0]


V=sc.zeros(d)

sc.sum(A,axis=0,out=V,dtype='int')
with sc.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):

    Vs = sc.true_divide( 1, V )
    Vs[ ~ sc.isfinite( Vs )] = 0  # -inf inf NaN

print Vs
```

Second attempt:

```
A=np.array([[0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
d=sc.shape(A)[0]

V=sc.zeros(d)

sc.sum(A,axis=0,out=V,dtype='int')

for i in range(0,d):
    if V[i]!=0:                       
        V[i]=1/V[i]
print V
```

Is there a faster way than this?As my running time is very poor.
Thanks

edit1: Do you think changing everything to csr sparse matrix format would make it faster?

Comment: What's the slow part?  The sum?  the divide?  the testing?  For large `d` I expect the iterative to be quite slow.  Unless your matrix is very sparse (10% or less) sparse matrices won't help.  And the sparse row sum returns a dense matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NumPy: Return 0 with divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero)

discusses various divide by zero options.  The accepted answer looks a lot like your first try.  But there's a new answer that might (?) be faster

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977222/901925

```
In [240]: V=A.sum(axis=0)
In [241]: np.divide(1,V,out=np.zeros(V.shape),where=V>0)
Out[241]: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
```

Your example is too small to make meaningful time tests on.  I don't have any intuition about the relative speeds (beyond my comment).

A recent SO question pointed out that the `out` parameter is required with `where` in the latest release (1.13) but optional in earlier ones.