# Python: Is there a NumPy function which takes from one array when mask is true and another when mask is false?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wish to divide an array `numerators` by an array `denominators`, but some elements in `denominators` may be zero. The resulting element at those indices should be zero as well. Is there a function in NumPy which picks elements from `numerators / denominators` where `denominators` isn't zero, and from a zero array otherwise?

I looked into boolean masking, but that would take multiple lines, since I would have to mask `denominators` in order to not get any division-by-zero errors, as well as the result in order to set those elements to zero.

I could swear I've seen such a function but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)?

Comment: np.where and np.divide have some issues; refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/how-to-return-0-with-divide-by-zero for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options available:

1. Ufuncs like `np.divide` support a `where` mask as of numpy version 1.7:

   ```
   quotients = np.divide(numerators, denominators, out=np.zeros(np.broadcast(numerators, denominators).shape, where=denominators != 0)
   ```
2. Use masked arrays:

   ```
   quotients = (numerators / np.ma.array(denominators, mask=denominators)).data
   ```

   This masks all elements of denominators that are zero, performs the division without changing them, and extracts the unmasked array.
3. Use masking by hand. This will be more than one line, but you can turn it into a function for future use:

   ```
   quotients = np.zeros(np.broadcast(numerators, denominators).shape)
   mask = ~denominators
   quotients[mask] = numerators[mask] / denominators[mask]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   quotients = np.empty(np.broadcast(numerators, denominators).shape)
   mask = ~denominators
   quotients[mask] = numerators[mask] / denominators[mask]
   quotients[mask] = 0
   ```

The knee-jerk response to use `np.where` does not work in this case. You end up pre-computing `numerators / denominators`, as in `np.where(denominators, numerators / denominators, 0)`, which defeats the entire purpose. Alternatively, you end up replacing the mask with `np.where(denominators)`, but at that point a mask is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`np.divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html). You can use a condition on your denominator array in the `where` parameter to put a condition on the division: `where=denominators!=0`. This will keep the value of the first array, however.

You can ommit the `where` parameter all together, which gives a warning and a 0 in the place where the denominator was 0.

You can also create a zeros array (`np.zeros(shape)`) and give that as array to which the `divide` method should write its result. In combination with the `where` parameter, this will give the correct result without a warning.

Comment: The where parameter to ufunc is not a lambda

Comment: Ah thanks @MadPhysicist, changed my answer.

Comment: You'll want `!=0` negative is ok

Comment: Right again! :p

Answer (score 0):

```
inds = np.where(denominators!=0)
ratio = np.zeros(numerators.shape)
ratio[inds] = nominators[inds]/denominators[inds]
```

Or, even more compact version:

```
np.where(denominators!=0,nominators/denominators,0)
```

The second approach gives what you want, but raises RuntimeWarning. You'll still get the desired values, though.

Comment: The "more compact" version will raise the error

Comment: For `nominators = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and `denominators = np.array([1, 0, 2, 0, 5])` it returns `array([1. , 0. , 1.5, 0. , 1. ])`. I've just literally tried it.

Comment: With no warnings? Because then all of this is pointless and you can just do `nominators / denominators`

Comment: With RuntimeWarning. But it's not error, and it returns desired result.

Comment: Yes, but OP is specifically asking not to do that.

Comment: simply `nominators / denominators` returns `array([1. , inf, 1.5, inf, 1. ])` which is not what OP wants to get, as far as I understand the question.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I'll leave the second approach with adequate note though.