# Division by zero python (some entries in a list)

Tags: python

i have a list with entries where some of them can be 0 - now i want to invert this list and replace the "undefined entries" - where 1/0 occurs with 0 - unfortunately this does not work:

```
noise_term = 1.0/np.sqrt(A*g)
if noise_term.any() != 0:
    noise_term = noise_term
else:
    noise_term = 0
```

what is the best way to solve this? i have also thought about doing this with while: True?

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add an example of what is inside `noise_term` and what is an invalid value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return 0 with divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/how-to-return-0-with-divide-by-zero)

Comment: Check my answers with scaler and numpy array way of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use a try:except to solve this -

**METHOD 1: IF noise_term is a scalar**

```
#How it works - TRY applying an operation and if exception occurs, run EXCEPT
try:
    noise_term = 1.0/np.sqrt(A*g)
except:
    noise_term = 0
```

**METHOD 2: IF noise_term is an array**

If you want to operate over an array of elements at once then you can use the parameters in `np.divide` to handle the divide by zero -

```
n = 1  #Numerator
d = np.sqrt(A*g)  #Array of denominators

np.divide(n, d, out=np.zeros_like(d), where=d!=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if np.sqrt(A*g) != 0:
    noise_term = 1.0/np.sqrt(A*g)
else:
    noise_term = 0
```